# What considerations should I take to train my transformer model?

Tags: training, transformer, image-segmentation, testing

I want to train my vision transformer model on a benchmark for an image segmentation task: ([LoveDA: A Remote Sensing Land-Cover Dataset for Domain Adaptive Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08733)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Junjue-Wang/LoveDA)), but I don't get any acceptable result from my model.

I don't have a good result either in evaluation nor (obviously) in test.

I'm frustrated since I have trained my model with different parameters: learning rate : [0.001,0001, 6e-e].

The training datasets include about 3000 images, the number of epochs is 1500.

I have used different loss functions: Cross Entropy, Dice loss, Focal loss, and a combination of those losses.

So, I'm wondering if anyone has any experience that could help me find a solution and improve my model's performance?

Comment: How does the loss function behave during training?

Comment: thanks Lee,
well cross entropy works better than any of them it decreases gradually, but after about 1200 epochs it will stop decreasing
Also I have checked the model with more general dataset, it was working fine 
but still have difficulty in compareto other deep learning like deeplab

Comment: @sarayaghoobi Edit your post to include the plots of the loss and other metrics, if possible. Said that, a training dataset of 3000 images seems to be very small. How many training parameters does your model have?

Comment: Have you tried a learning rate schedule? A lower learning rate might help the model fine tune after converging at a poor solution.